# ошибка компиляции node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

я создал файл ts и преобразовал его в js после чего попытался скомпилировать в node.js. ошибка-не видит метод get

```
"use strict";
 exports.__esModule = true;
 var axios_1 = require("axios");
 var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
 axios_1["default"].get(url).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
 });
```

Comment: А скрипт-то у Вас работал? axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com'; - так работают с defaults. А так с get: axios.get(url[, config])

Comment: Может тут axios_1["default"] <- может тут добавить 's' "defaults"

Comment: было бы здорово писать ошибку!